# Cron job management

Tags: cron, calendar, scheduler

What would you use as cron jobs management tool, viewer (web application based on PHP / MySQL would be preferred / gui required)?

Having an overview of multiple jobs running periodically is crucial for me.
Something offering calendar views or gantt diagrams would be great.

Some open source scheduler based on cron jobs which would offer such views would help equally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `crontab -e`, `crontab -l` and `su` or `sudo`. ;-)

Comment: These are the only ones that I know of as well.

Comment: Thanks but I would rather be looking for something more handy (which might be integrated with a calendar for instance).